# mySQL - Grouping values based on consecutive differences

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table in my database that contains an ID and DATETIME column, here is some sample data:

```
ID   |   DATETIME
1    |   2014-05-06 01:12
1    |   2014-05-06 01:30
1    |   2014-05-06 01:45
1    |   2014-05-06 02:59
2    |   2014-05-06 01:17
2    |   2014-05-06 01:18
2    |   2014-05-06 01:19
2    |   2014-05-06 02:00
```

I need to produce a query that determines the ID belonging to the object that has the longest time between its `DATETIME` values, where the time between consecutive `DATETIME` values does not exceed 20 minutes.

For example, in the sample data, I would want to return 1 as it has `DATETIME` values from `(01:12 - 01:45)` without having a consecutive difference of 20 minutes between `DATETIME` values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you will need a self-join.  Because if you had 10 entries for an ID, your 20 minute gap might be between entries 3-6 vs 1-4 or even 4-9.  So the second instance of the join would be on the same ID and have a date time higher than that of the primary entry, but less than 20 minutes.  Then, it could be ordered by the time-gap and limit to the one you want.  Something like:

```
select
      YT.ID,
      YT.DTColumn,
      MAX( YT2.DTColumn ) as MaxDateWithin20Minutes
   from
      YourTable YT
         JOIN YourTable YT2
            ON YT.ID = YT2.ID
           AND YT.DTColumn < YT2.DTColumn
           AND YT2.DTColumn <= date_add( YT.DTColumn, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE )
   group by
      YT.ID,
      YT.DTColumn
   order by
      timediff(MAX( YT2.DTColumn ), YT.DTColumn) DESC
   limit 
      1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the next (or previous) value and get the time difference.  I think the following does what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.datetime
              from table t2
              where t2.id = t.id and t2.datetime < t.datetime
              order by t2.datetime desc
             ) prev_datetime
      from table t
     ) t
where datetime <= prev_datetime + interval 20 minutes
order by timestampdiff(second, prev_datetime, datetime) desc
limit 1;
```